# How to use JNA PostMessage in Java 8

Tags: java, winapi, java-8, jna

The following code worked in older Java versions, but seems to have quit working in Java 8.  Would anyone know why this happened, and how to fix it?

```
public static String notifyExternalApplication() {
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer("");
    try {
        User32.HWND fusionmsg = User32.INSTANCE.FindWindow("TFusionHdtvTray","HDTV Tray");
        int wmUserPlusOffset = 0x400 + 5014;
        User32.WPARAM two = new User32.WPARAM(2L);
        User32.LPARAM zero = new User32.LPARAM(0L);
        boolean fusResult = User32.INSTANCE.PostMessage(fusionmsg, wmUserPlusOffset, two, zero);
        buf.append(" fusResult was " + fusResult + "\n");
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        buf.append(" " + e.getMessage());
    } 
    return new String(buf);
}
```

Edit: When this code runs in all OS's, it returns " fusResult was true".  It's just that in the newer Java version, it seems to have no effect.

Edit2: 
*Research done* - Ran this same code on the same system, but with different versions of Java.  Results posted here.
*Clarity* - The exact code is posted and the result stated.
*Result if question is answered (usefulness)* - Myself, and other coders who use this technique will have an option to get their code working again.

Comment: What happened when you ran it? Did you get an error? If so, please post the output from the error.

Comment: This code never worked, except by pure luck. Calling `PostMessage` passing objects with automatic lifetime is a bug waiting to happen. Use `SendMessage` when you are not controlling object lifetimes. Hoping that the system would marshal message parameters for non-system messages (i.e. messages >= 0x400) is too optimistic to be true. Stop doing what you're doing and find a real solution (like using the automation interface instead).

Comment: Very lucky then, since it certainly worked on many dozens of machines and configurations as long as it wasn't Java 8.   But I'll admit to not knowing anything about this API; I just copied this from somewhere.  I'll try the SendMessage API instead.  Thanks for that idea.

Comment: As far as I can see, these objects are just JNA-specific wrappers around their native data and when making the native call it will actually use the native data, not the Java objects. In other words, I see no problem with the life time of the Java objects. What’s striking me is that you are not checking the result of `FindWindow`, so you don’t know whether *that* operation succeeded, and since `PostMessage` accepts `NULL`, changing the meaning of the call, such an error may remain unnoticed.

Comment: @Holger: Native objects or not, the call to `PostMessage` immediately returns, and someone will have to clean up. Since `PostMessage` can have zero or more receivers, the receiver(s) cannot perform cleanup. That leaves only one option: Automatic resource management, with the implications I pointed out in my previous comment. The code has a dependency on good fortune - a limited resource.

Comment: @IInspectable: I have the strong feeling that you are not aware that what you see here is **Java** code. The objects created here will live as long as there are references to it. The term “Automatic resource management” does not apply to them. If another thread held a reference to one of these objects, that expanded its lifetime. Nevertheless, the stub code of JNA will *copy* the actual values (which are just integer values and plain pointers) *before* making the native call, which will then be asynchronous, but *native Windows functions never hold references to Java objects*.

Comment: @Holger: Plain pointers have to point to something. That something will have to get cleaned up, be it a native resource or a Java object. That cleanup cannot be performed by the receiver, but has to be performed by the caller (automatically). Since the respective resource cannot safely be tracked through references, it may get disposed, before the receiver can even access it. This is irrespective of whether the code is Java. This being Java merely lengthens the window of fortune, under which the code appears to work.

Comment: “Since the respective resource cannot safely be tracked through references, it may get disposed, before the receiver can even access it.” You should learn what memory management aka garbage collection means. In Java, reference *are* tracked safely. The only native pointer involved is the `HWND` result of `FindWindow`. Ask Microsoft about how to ensure that the window is not closed between `FindWindow` and `PostMessage`, none of their example code attempts to do anything about it. They seem to assume that `PostMessage` can handle the situation that the `HWND` goes stale in-between.

Comment: @Holger: [`WPARAM` and `LPARAM` are **pointers**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383751.aspx) (in general). Whatever those parameters point to, needs to live long enough for the receiver to use. Since no synchronization of any sort is implemented, the code works by **coincidence**. This is unrelated to the fact, whether automatic garbage collection or manual resource management is in use.